# Best way to remove extra marks from an RTF text

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an RTF that looks like this:

> {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\uc0\deff0{\fonttbl\r\n{\f0\fswiss\fcharset0\fprq2 Arial;}\r\n{\f1\froman\fcharset2\fprq2 Symbol;}}\r\n{\colortbl;\red0\green0\blue0;\red255\green255\blue255;}\r\n\r\n\deftab1134\pard\plain\f0\fs24 hohohoHi\pard\par\par }

There is an extra \pard\par at the end of it that I want to remove it. I think it is some bug with the text editor I have to use or something like that adding extra \pard\par to the end of RTF,  BUT I also want to keep the \pard\par if users have intentionally added them to their text. So I think I am asking of a good way to remove the extra \pard\par from the end of an RTF, but only remove one pair of them because users may have entered some break lines intentionally...

String methods? RegEx?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that can be maddening.

One way around that is to `SelectAll` and grab the `SelectedRtf` instead of the `Rtf`.

To avoid flashing the user, it's easier to create a quick temporary RichTextBox control, like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine(richTextBox1.Rtf);
sb.AppendLine();

string myRTF = string.Empty;
using (RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox()) {
  rtb.Rtf = richTextBox1.Rtf;
  rtb.SelectAll();
  sb.AppendLine(rtb.SelectedRtf);
}

string results = sb.ToString();
```

Here is the outcome of the two methods with just a "Hello" and a single line return:

> {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deftab1134{\fonttbl{\f0\fswiss\fprq2\fcharset0 Arial;}}
> \viewkind4\uc1\pard\lang1033\f0\fs24 Hello\par
> \par
> }
>
> {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deftab1134{\fonttbl{\f0\fswiss\fprq2\fcharset0 Arial;}}
> \viewkind4\uc1\pard\lang1033\f0\fs24 Hello\par
> }